# POSTing Nested JSON in AngularJS [400 error]

Tags: json, angularjs, http-status-code-400

Part of my HTML

```
    <div>House Details:
        <input type ="number" ng-model="house.totalArea" placeholder="total_area">
        <input type="number" ng-model="house.cost" placeholder="Cost">    
        </div>

        <div>Address:
        <input type="text" ng-model="house.address.state" placeholder="state">
        <input type="text" ng-model="house.address.city" placeholder="city ">
  </div>
```

Angular:`$scope.house = {}; 
       $scope.house.address = {}; 
       $scope.processRentForm = function () {
       console.log($scope.house);
       $http.post("http://localhost:8080/Property101/house/addHouse", $scope).
       error(function (data, status, headers, config) {alert("Submit failed!!");`

Code works fine for just $scope.house but

I'm getting a 400 eror ( syntactically incorrect) for nested JSON which is forming as

```
Object {address: Object, totalArea: 1000}
```

I have a Address class inside a House class on server side which have the similar no./names of parameters as the JSON I'm trying to send.

Some of the examples at SO have "house.address.state" syntax. 
I'm new angular, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before sending the request JSON onto server side do the following 2 steps,

1) var reqObj = JSON.stringify($scope.house);

2) var requestJson = JSON.parse(reqObj)

Now send the requestJson as request. It should work.